# Python unittest ModuleNotFound for import from same module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-unittest

I kept getting **ModuleNotFound** error when trying to create unit test on my module.
Here is my folder structure

```
- mod1/
  - __init__.py
  - file1.py
  - numbers.py
- tests/
  - __init__.py
  - test_file1.py
```

The problem is in `file1.py` there is this statement `from numbers import five`.

file1.py

```
from numbers import five

def five_plus_one():
    return five()+1
```

test_file1.py

```
import unittest
from mod1.file1 import five_plus_one

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.mock.patch('mod1.file1.five')
    def test_five_plus_one(self, five_mock):
        five_mock.return_value = 7
        self.assert_true(8, five_plus_one())
```

Using nosetests, this will generate this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numbers'
```

From going through multiple stackoverflow questions, here is what if tried.

1. Removing and adding `__init__.py`

   I've tried removing one, in both places and removed both, and it doesn't change the error
2. replace the patch with `@unittest.mock.patch('numbers.five')` or `@unittest.mock.patch('mod1.numbers.five')`
3. using `import numbers` instead of `from numbers import five` in `file1.py`
4. using local import, but it produces this error

```
AttributeError: <module 'mod1.file1' from '/mod1/file1.py'> does not have the attribute 'five'
```

The only time it ever worked is if I modify `file1.py` to have `from .numbers import five` but it caused this error when running the code regularly

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I'm quite new to python and don't really understand the namespace and how it imports.

Note. I wouldn't be able to modify PYTHONPATH or the way this code is being ran.

Answer (score 0):

In `file1.py` replace your current import with this:

`from mod1.numbers import five`

Honestly, I don't know how it works either. Always had to do this for multi-folder projects and never really questioned it.

Comment: I did this, but running it normally will cause error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'```